# Fill holes/blocks in masked frames

Tags: python, numpy, mask

I want to fill the "holes" in my masked image based on certain criteria. I have the following raw `frame`:

[image]

Next, I apply a mask over this frame which gives `masked`:

[image]

Now I want to divide the frame into *16x16 blocks*. In order to define `block(x,y)`, we define a set of pixels in the *x-th* and *y-th* block in vertical and horizontal direction.
A block is defined as `non-field (field)` if the percentage of black pixels within the block is `larger (smaller)` than `0.5`. The code looks as follows:

```
def blocked_img(img, x_pixels, y_pixels):
   blocked = img.copy()
   gray = cv2.cvtColor(blocked, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

   for x in range(0, blocked.shape[1], x_pixels):
      for y in range(0, blocked.shape[0], y_pixels):
         block = gray[y:y+y_pixels, x:x+x_pixels]
         if (cv2.countNonZero(block) / block.size) < 0.5:
            # non-field
            cv2.rectangle(blocked, (x, y), (x+x_pixels, y+y_pixels), (0,255,255), 2)
         else:
            # field
            break

    return blocked
```

`masked.shape` returns the following:

```
 (720, 1280, 3)
```

So, I call the function `blocked_img` by using:

```
blocked = blocked_img(masked, 80, 45)     #  divide by 16
```

The output, `blocked`, looks as follows:

[image]

At the moment, my code is written that as soon as the `0.5-threshold` is not reached, it loops to the next column. It can be seen that in the columns on the right, this method does not produce the desirable outcome as it stops prematurely (columns 9, 11, 12, 13, 16 to be precise)

I would like to continue the loop within the column if one the two following is in place:

- current block is non-field if previous block is non-field AND [next block is non-field OR next_next block is non-field]
- current block is non-field if [previous_previous block is non-field OR previous block is non-field] AND next block is non-field

Rewritten,

```
   block(x,y) = 1 if [block(x-1,y) = 1 and {block(x+1,y) = 1 or block(x+2,y) = 1}] or [{block(x-2, y) = 1 or block(x-1, y) = 1} and block(x+1, y) = 1]       # where 1 = non-field
```

Any idea how I can include this in my code? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def blocked_img(img, x_pixels, y_pixels):

   blocked = img.copy()
   gray = cv2.cvtColor(blocked, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

   for x in range(0, blocked.shape[1], x_pixels):
      for y in range(0, blocked.shape[0], y_pixels):
         block = gray[y:y+y_pixels, x:x+x_pixels]
         next_block = gray[y+y_pixels:y+(2*y_pixels), x:x+x_pixels]
         next_next_block = gray[y+(2*y_pixels):y+(3*y_pixels), x:x+x_pixels]
         if (cv2.countNonZero(block) / block.size) < 0.75:
            # non-field
            cv2.rectangle(blocked, (x, y), (x+x_pixels, y+y_pixels), (0,0,0), -1)
         else:
            if ((cv2.countNonZero(next_block) / block.size) < 0.75) or ((cv2.countNonZero(next_next_block) / block.size) < 0.75):
               # non-field
               cv2.rectangle(blocked, (x, y), (x+x_pixels, y+y_pixels), (0,0,0), -1)
            else:
               # field
               break
return blocked
```

I am not sure whether this is the fastest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looping through your blocks multiple times. Here's how I'm thinking -

```
def blocked_img(img, x_pixels, y_pixels):
   blocked = img.copy()
   blocks = np.zeros((blocked.shape[1]//x_pixels,blocked.shape[0]//y_pixels)) ##array to keep track of blocks status
   gray = cv2.cvtColor(blocked, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   prev_num_blocks = np.sum(blocks)
   for x in range(0, blocked.shape[1], x_pixels):
      for y in range(0, blocked.shape[0], y_pixels):
         block = gray[y:y+y_pixels, x:x+x_pixels]
         if (cv2.countNonZero(block) / block.size) < 0.5:
            # non-field
            cv2.rectangle(blocked, (x, y), (x+x_pixels, y+y_pixels), (0,255,255), 2)
            blocks[x,y] = 1
         else:
            # field
            continue

while (np.sum(blocks)>prev_num_blocks): ##keep going unless no change occurs in prev loop
for x in range(2, blocks.shape[0]-2, x_pixels):
  for y in range(2, blocks.shape[1]-2, y_pixels):
      ###the advance update rule here
      if (.....):
          blocks[x,y]=1
          cv2.rectangle(blocked,...) ##recreate the rect indices using the x,y

return blocked
```

The while loop is needed in my point of view as a change in a blocks status to non-field in cycle 1, affects the blocks previous to it in the column as it becomes the next_block and next_next block for others.

This is probably not the most efficient way, but would definitely converge and exit the while loop.

Comment: hey Kartik, thanks for taking the time to answer my question. Ideally, I want to use the code for realtime processing, so a second loop is not desirable to be honest!